# Can't find Eyefinity for ATI AMD 6770M HD

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, hdmi, eyefinity

My Notebook details: HP Pavilion dv7 6b21em
CPU: 3.2 GHz Quad Core i7
RAM: 12GB DDR5
GPU: ATI (AMD) 6770M HD 2GB Dedicated RAM  & Intel HD Mobile (Switchable Graphic Card)
OS: Windows 7 Ultimate x64

Output: **1x HDMI, 1x VGA**, (2x 3.0 USB)

I downloaded my GPU drivers from HP Drivers & Support website but the Catalyst Control Center does not offer Eyefinity anywhere not even greyed out option as if it were not available.

Do I need to download Eyefinity separately or am I missing something. I tried installing updated drivers and CCC using ATI/AMD Automatic Driver Detection tool from their website thinking the HP site may be outdated but the app gives an error message that it does not find supported hardware.

In my BIOS i changed my GPU setting from Dynamic to Fixed so it never uses the integrated Intel GPU. I tried running that application to update drivers again and same error.

Things I checked:

- Graphic card can output to both HDMI and VGA ports at the same time with no problem.
- Graphic card can output to both HDMI and VGA and both USB 3.0 screens at the same time so output is not a problem. I had 4 external screens connected to the notebook.
- I checked that under dxdiag that the GPU is detected and selected
- I checked that under my display settings ATI GPU is selected and it is.

At the moment I have two external screens one is connected to HDMI and other one to VGA. I want to try out Eyefinity with a online Game to have a unified screen. Anyone familiar with this problem ?

Thansk for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Eyefinity configuration should be part of the Catalyst Control Center software. I have not used it on a laptop but here is a shot from my desktop

[image: CCC]

Your notebook may not support the required disaply output (see [AMD FAQ](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/amd-eyefinity-technology/how-to/Pages/faqs.aspx#notebook-availability)). Check with HP support but that may be the reason that it is not showing up.

> Yes! AMD Eyefinity technology support is also built into many of our
>   notebook GPUs, but it is up to the manufacturer of the notebook to
>   equip their product with the necessary display outputs.
>
> Notebooks that offer the outputs to activate AMD Eyefinity technology
>   include the Alienware M17x and the HP ENVY 17. Please note that the
>   default configurations for these notebooks may not include AMD Radeon™
>   graphics, so be sure to verify that you have selected an AMD solution
>   before checkout.

Comment: I dont have a display port turns out i need a display port and a hub.